# Differentiating a multivariable integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to analyze a function $F$ of $k$ variables, $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_k$. Specifically, if we let

$$G(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k) = \int_{0}^{b(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)}F(y,x_2,\cdots,x_k)dy,$$

is there any way I can express either $\frac{dG}{dx_i}$ or $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}$ in terms of the derivatives of $F$ and $b$? I am aware of Leibniz's rule for differentiating under the integral sign, but that would still leave expressions with integrals of partial derivatives, and if possible I would love to learn about some technique that would allow me to express these derivatives just in terms of $F$, $b$ and their derivatives.

I'm hopeful that there is a way to do this because the integration is only with respect to one of the variables of $F$. We can assume that all the applicable integrals and derivatives exist.

Comment: You use the same variable name as an integration label and as an upper limit. This easily leads to mistakes when doing derivatives. I suggest writing it as $\int^{b(x_1,\ldots)} F(t,x_2,\ldots) dt$ or similar to avoid this issue (in this form you see that the $x_1$ derivative will be different than the rest). And yes you can use Leibniz rule here.

Comment: Can you update the question in order to avoid using $x_1$ as both an integral variable and a variable used in the bound (through $b$)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Denoting $H(t, x_2, \dots, x_n)= \int_0^t F(y, x_2, \dots, x_n) \ dy$, we have

$$ G(x_1, \dots, x_n) = H(b(x_1, \dots, x_n), x_2, \dots, x_n).$$

Then for $i \ge 2$, applying chain rule, we get:

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}$$

The [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) leads to

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}(t, x_2, \dots, x_n) = F(t, x_2, \dots, x_n)$$

and derivative under integral sign to

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}(t, x_2, \dots, x_n) = \int_0^t\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(y, \dots, x_n) \ dy$$

Summarizing all we finally get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)&= \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_i}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)F(b(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n), x_2, \dots, x_n)\\
&+ \int_0^{b(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(y, \dots, x_n) \ dy
\end{aligned}$$

The $x_1$-partial derivative is simpler and equal to

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)= \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)F(b(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n), x_2, \dots, x_n) dy$$

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter explains the issue.

Comment: @Winther I’m supposing that $i\ge 2$ here. If not, even the original question doesn’t make sense. And then I use partial derivatives.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional elements. Rather than stating the derivative of ... is not, it would be good that you say what it is with the proper elements.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, thank you for your answer but as user Winther points out, if we take $k = 2$, $F = x_2$ and $b = 1$ then $G = \int_{0}^{1}x_2 dy = x_2$ so that $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_2} = 1$ but $\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2} = 0$

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the comment. I was missing one term in applying the chain rule for the derivative $H$.